# Find XPath when .net xslt, XslCompiledTransform, and a serialized object

Tags: .net, vb.net, xslt, xpath

I am trying to create an email template using xslt and fill in the data with xml (a serialized object) and .net's XslCompiledTransform to process the transformation.

I am using .NET 2.0 and Visual Studio 2012. To get a prototype, I created a simple project that contains a page that outputs the results of the transformation for testing purposes.

With the current code, I can't seem to find the correct XPaths to the elements of the serialized object.

Create a class named UserProfile:

```
<Serializable>
Public Class UserProfile
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Create a folder called Templates and in it, create an xslt file "TestEmail.xslt"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        First Name is <xsl:value-of select="UserProfile/FirstName"/><br/>
        Last Name is <xsl:value-of select="UserProfile/LastName"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Create a Web Forms file called Email.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Email.aspx.vb" Inherits="Email.Email" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Literal ID="output" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the Email.aspx.vb file:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.XPath
Imports System.Xml.Xsl
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Public Class Email
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim client As UserProfile

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        client = New UserProfile
        client.FirstName = "First"
        client.LastName = "Last"
        output.Text = BuildEmail()
    End Sub

    Private Function BuildEmail()
        Dim email As String = ""
        Dim document As XmlDocument     
        Dim navigator As XPathNavigator 
        Dim transformer As XslCompiledTransform 
        Dim output As StringWriter
        Dim serializationStream As New MemoryStream()
        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(client.GetType, "UserProfile")
        Try

            serializer.Serialize(serializationStream, client)
            serializationStream.Position = 0

            document = New XmlDocument()
            Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(serializationStream)

            document.Load(reader)

            // create navigator
            navigator = document.CreateNavigator

            // load style sheet
            transformer = New XslCompiledTransform(True)
            Dim templatePath = Server.MapPath("Templates/TestEmail.xslt")
            transformer.Load(templatePath)

            // transform XML data
            output = New StringWriter()
            transformer.Transform(navigator, Nothing, output)

            email = output.ToString

            // close streams
            output.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try


        Return email
    End Function

End Class
```

That should be enough code to reproduce the issue of not finding the XPath to the elements.

**EDIT:** Changed Last Name is  to Last Name is  in the xslt doc.

**EDIT:** Removed some comments that were converted to //

Comment: `Last Name is <xsl:value-of select="UserProfile/FirstName"/>` looks definitely wrong, should be `Last Name is <xsl:value-of select="UserProfile/LastName"/>`, to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the Xslt email template to work by removing the creation of a namespace in the XML document.

In Email.aspx.vb, I changed

```
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(client.GetType, "UserProfile")
```

to

```
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(client.GetType)
```

The addition of a default namespace is not needed in this case, so I simply removed that parameter.

If someone can get it to work with using a default namespace, I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks